# Lua code to check and print whether a number is even or odd

Tags: redis, lua

I am unable to figure out a practice question which is asking to create a lua file to check whether a number is even or odd by using redis queries as well.

The code that I have written in lua file is like

```
local myval = 94

if (myval % 2 == 0 ) then
    redis.call()
else
    redis.call()
end
```

Now as a part of the statement the question is asking like below

> Declare a local variable with name myval and assign 94 to it. maintain
> key value as number.

I am unable to understand the second part of this statement. How should I set the key value along with the local variable declaraion in lua file.

> maintain key value as number.

Can you please help me to understand this? what needs to be done here?

finally, my code will look like this, which will set the key-value depends on the myval number.

```
local myval = 94
    
    if (myval % 2 == 0 ) then
        redis.call(‘set’, KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
    else
        redis.call(‘set’, KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
    end
```

Comment: Better ask whoever gave you this practice task. Those words are really unclear.

Comment: I think you have missed something in the question. And in the last piece of code there is definitely something wrong if you do exactly the same thing in the `then` clause as in the `else` clause - there is no point executing the `if` if both parts are the same!

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Yes, else clause will set the different value for the key. In this case I will set it to "Odd" and in the if condition I will set it to "Even". I am just unclear about the words. "maintain key value as number". So basically wondering if a key value can be set by any eval opertaion while declaring a variable in lua file. So that it can be executed via Redis scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish without more details.
This should retrieve odd or even value stored in the 94th position.
Might need to flip ARGV numbers;  haven't seen what's in database, or expected output.

```
local myval = 94

if ( myval %2 == 0 ) then  --  even
    print(  redis .call( ‘get’, KEYS[myval], ARGV[1] )  )
else
    print(  redis .call( ‘get’, KEYS[myval], ARGV[2] )  )
end
```